# how to change the default application for Mac OS quick look

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

Is it possible to change the application being used to quick look a certain file extension in Mac OS. (I'm using Mountain Lion).

For example, right now the .properties file quick look is always showing as a black box (terminal-like icon with "exec" text). 
How can I change this quick look to show the file content instead, using some kind of text editor.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possile via QuickLook plugins, namely QLStephen. You can download and install this pluing from http://whomwah.github.com/qlstephen/.

Answer (score 2):

QLStephen described by @jobatabs is only one of the many plugins.  In fact, at the time of this answer (2021), you can find various kinds of plugins to install to 'quicklook' various types of file extensions. You can find them here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/quick-look-plugins